# how to compare text box value with the option value of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to compare the text box value with the option values of a drop down list.
if they are same alert box should appear.

Comment: Great! These sound like reasonable requirements and about 3 lines of JavaScript - what have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" />
<select name="selectvalue">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<script>
 $("select[name=selectvalue]").change(function(){
     if( $(this).val() == $("input[name=textbox]").val() )
         alert("Value is same!!!");
 })
</script>
```

You can fire this check on submits also or anytime u want. You didnt mention when you want the alert. On change of select value or change of input text box value or on a button click.

Answer (score -3):

```
// html code
<input type="text" id="textboxID" value="1" />
<select id="selectID">
    <option value="1" selected>First</option>
</select>

// the script
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($("#textboxID").val() === $("#selectID").val())
        alert("The values are equal.");
</script>
```

Comment: This does not address the problem really. When does this code run? Where is the event you check based on? In what context? Not to mention feeding a user who asked a question with no effort or real context.